# Rails: Active Record Group By Delegate Join Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, group-by, delegates

I have a Task model:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  delegate :workspace, :to => :project, :allow_nil => true
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :importance
  belongs_to :urgency
end
```

I want to display all tasks grouped by Workspace.  My Controller looks like this:

```
  def workspace
    @task = Task.joins(:project => :workspace).joins(:urgency).where(urgencies: {urgency_value: 7}).group_by(&:workspace_id)
  end
```

My tasks table has a `project_id`.  In my projects table, each record has a `workspace_id`.  What I want to do is to use the `workspace_id` to group all of my tasks.

Comment: try changing the group to `group('projects.workspace_id')`

Comment: This seems to return a single record for each group instead of creating a hash where the key is the workspace_id and the index contains all of the individual records which I can then loop through.